# Devise+CanCan strange behaviour when deleting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I have implemented authentication with devise and manage role permissions with CanCan. My application manages Recipes and when I destroy a Recipe, I get my session closed and redirects me to sign_in view...

If I don't check authentication and permissions (see recipes_controller above) it works fine.

It's very strange and I have no idea why this happens. Please help.

Thanks

**LOG:**

```
 Started POST "/recipes/21" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Dec 08 19:53:30 +0100 2011
 Processing by RecipesController#destroy as HTML
 Parameters: {"id"=>"21"}
 User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 5 LIMIT 1
 Completed 401 Unauthorized in 44ms

 Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Dec 08 19:53:30 +0100 2011  
 Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
 Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (2.5ms)
 Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (14.2ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 52ms (Views: 20.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**RECIPES_CONTROLLER:**

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!
load_and_authorize_resource

def destroy
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    @recipe.destroy
    redirect_to recipes_url, :notice => "Successfully destroyed Recipe."
end
```

**ABILITY:**

```
class Ability
include CanCan::Ability

def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user
    if user.role? :super_admin
        can :manage, :all
    else if user.role? :super_read_admin
        can :read, :all
    else
        # manage reciped he owns
        can :manage, Recipe do |recipe|
        recipe.owner == user
    end
end
end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer, per asker (see comments below)

You must make sure you include `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` in your layout.

============================

(Original reply)

From `Completed 401 Unauthorized in 44ms` it looks like your user is not allowed to destroy this recipe. Check that `recipe.owner.id` is 5...

Try this in the console:

```
user = User.find(5)
puts user.role
ability = Ability.new(user)
ability.can? :destroy, Recipe.find(21)
```

What is the output of the second and the last commands ?

Comment: See updates to the answer: writing code in comments isn't very readable... Let me know the output.

Comment: Not sure if you are expecting my answer here... The second command does not work for me but if I put "puts user.role? :super_admin" it says True. The last command says True. If the user don't have permission to destroy recipe the application will not close the devise session

Comment: And if you comment out `load_and_authorize_resource` everything works properly?

Comment: It works properly if I comment both load_and_authorize_resource and before_filter :authenticate_user!. If I comment only before_filter:authenticate_user! I have: 'Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 105ms' instead of error 401

Comment: But what if you comment ONLY `load_and_authorize_resource` ?

Comment: ONLY load_and_authorize_resource gives me 'Completed 401 Unauthorized in 169ms' (I think error seems to be with authenticate_user!)

Comment: Your user is somehow not authenticated... That's where you'll have to start your search. Good luck !

Comment: ANSWER: including <%= csrf_meta_tags %> in layout solved the problem. Thanks!